# Zone Mapping GPO

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-server, group-policy, gpo

I have a problem with Zone Mapping settings I want to add files from share when open exe to Intranet zone by gpo.

I try settings with Zone Assigment List

\\myserver\myfile*  1

\\myserver           1

And still when I open this exe files I get security warnings. How to do this with security standards and add this UNC paths to exclude ?